# From Mathematica to phyton

Tags: python, sympy, wolfram-mathematica

I'm very new in Mathematica and python, but I want to transcribe my code in Mathematica to Sympy because the code in python is free, and so I can to share my words of the university, But I don't understand how to begin the following code in python. I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Define the fields.

```
FR[x_, y_] = Simplify[y + \[Epsilon] (a01 + a11 x + a21 y + a31 x y + a41 x^2 + a51 y^2 ) ]

GR[x_, y_] = Simplify[-x + \[Epsilon] (b01 + b11 x + b21 y + b31 x y + b41 x^2 + b51 y^2  )]
```

Change to polar coordinates:

```
RR = FullSimplify[Collect[Factor[(Cos[\[Theta]] FR[x, y] + Sin[\[Theta]] GR[x, y]) /. {x -> r Cos[\[Theta]], y -> r Sin[\[Theta]]}], r]]

\[CapitalTheta]R = FullSimplify[Factor[((Cos[\[Theta]] GR[x, y] - Sin[\[Theta]] FR[x, y])/
      r) /. {x -> r Cos[\[Theta]], y -> r Sin[\[Theta]]}]]
```

Take the Taylor series of following expression:

```
FFR = Simplify[Normal[Series[RR/\[CapitalTheta]R, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]]]
```

Comment: "SO isn't a free online coding service." I understand, but the true is that I can´t understand how define the field for example FR[x,y] since appears error for example the x is not defined and so on.  I just only need at least it.

Comment: You have to translate your code into Python syntax. A parser usually can do that for you if you can write your expression in a form the parser can recognize. SymPy has a `mathematica` parser, but it doesn't parse your first expression as written.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the latest development version of SymPy, in the class `MathematicaParser` there is a dictionary [mapping the expression nodes from Mathematica to their equivalent in SymPy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/258093ccf92892599456b53fa0a3dc15c780ce8c/sympy/parsing/mathematica.py#L947).

It's not a complete list, but contributions are welcome to expand it.

The development version of SymPy is currently able to parse Mathematica code into a form equivalent to its *FullForm*, see the [unit tests](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/258093ccf92892599456b53fa0a3dc15c780ce8c/sympy/parsing/tests/test_mathematica.py#L91) as an example.

Starting from the existing code, it is not too hard to create a Mathematica to SymPy code translator or interpreter. This could make for a nice Google Summer of Code (GSoC) project, if there are good applications.